# Como inserir um objeto e uma lista de objetos no mesmo request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um objeto fornecedor, e cada fornecedor tem diversos contatos, na pagina, tem uma aba para o cadastro de fornecedor, e outra aba para o cadastro dos contatos, a aba de cadastro de contatos tem um pequeno formulário, e abaixo uma tabela onde a cada item cadastrado no formulário, eu insiro na tabela usando JavaScript. Depois que essa pagina tiver com uma aba preenchida com os dados do fornecedor e na outra aba uma tabela HTML com uma lista de contatos, preciso enviar isso para controller para cadastrar no banco.

Na minha View uso uma ViewModel Assim:

```
public class FornecedorContatoViewModel
{
    public Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
    public Contato Contato { get; set; }
}
```

O formulário é feito com razor, e a tabela é HTML mesmo.

No controller, funcionaria algo do tipo:

```
public ActionResult Add(Fornecedor fornecedor, IList<Contato> contato)
{

}
```

E como fazer para que a tabela toda vá para a action em forma de uma lista (List nesse caso), como ficaria o submit, poderia fazer normalmente?

Comment: Tem sim e o código do controller tá corretíssimo.

Comment: @jbueno, está correto mesmo, ou você está sendo sarcastico?

Comment: Está correto, jovem. Eu não uso o site pra ser sarcástico. Claro que tem outras formas de fazer, algumas até mais indicadas dependendo do contexto do projeto. Mas dessa forma vai funcionar perfeitamente.

Comment: ah muito obrigado viu, é que já foram sarcástico comigo aqui, e eu imaginava que isso não ia funcionar não. Se você tiver algum link de algum artigo sobre as formas mais indicadas de fazer isso como você citou, poste como resposta que ai eu já marco sua resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: A intenção é não haver esse tipo de comportamento aqui. Sempre que acontecer você pode sinalizar o comentário (ou a publicação). O site tem uma [equipe de moderadores](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) que pode cuidar disto. Sobre responder: respostas apenas com links não são bem vistas (ou úteis pro site). Eu poderia criar uma resposta pra você, mas primeiro preciso entender qual é o problema propriamente dito. Você quer apenas um exemplo de como pode mandar dois parâmetros para o *controller*? Se você puder deixar a pergunta mais clara, seria bom [edit]. [+]

Comment: [+] Dessa forma a pergunta pode ser útil pra qualquer pessoa que tenha a mesma dúvida + no futuro e você vai ter sua resposta. Além disso, outros usuários podem publicar novas respostas mostrando outras maneiras de se fazer, etc.

Comment: Ok vou editar a pergunta e tentar deixar mais clara.

Comment: Então. Com sua edição ficou melhor. Agora minha ideia já é outra. Você não precisa de dois parâmetros na action `Add`. Precisa apenas de um `FornecedorContatoViewModel`. Ainda funciona da primeira forma, mas não vejo sentido em seguir dois padrões diferentes. Se você está usando com `ViewModel` siga neste caminho e seja feliz.

Comment: Realmente, agora que você falou faz mais sentido mesmo. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Fiquei pensando aqui agora, usando a ViewModel, como ela tem uma propriedade Contato e não um List<Contato>, será que ela receberia vários contatos inseridos na tabela?

Comment: Então. Eu estava escrevendo sobre isso. Dê uma olhada na resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funcionaria, embora não faça o mínimo sentido. Uma vez que você esteja usando ViewModels, pode simplesmente usá-la como parâmetro da sua action.

```
public ActionResult Add(FornecedorContatoViewModel fornecedorContatoVm)
{

}
```

Fora isso, sua ViewModel está errada. Ela deveria ter uma `List<Contato>` ao invés de `Contato`

```
public class FornecedorContatoViewModel
{
    public Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
    public List<Contato> Contatos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Certo, mas ai ão consigo fazer isso:  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contato.Email) eu poderia fazer no HTML sem problema mas como ficaria o name do campo, name = "Contato.Email"? Bati a mão no enter sem querer... :)

Comment: @AlanAlmeida Você vai ter percorrer a lista para mostrar os valores, normal. Da primeira forma você só poderia ter **um contato** para cada fornecedor, não me parece ser essa a intenção.

Comment: Sim a ideia é ter vários contatos, eu teria que percorrer a lista no controller certo? Pra pegar cada contato que veio da view. O que queria saber é para o asp.net fazer o data binding os atributos name dos campos HTML precisam ser o mesmo nome da propriedade do objeto que a action recebe, certo? No caso, se eu usar razor quando coloco model. pra exibir a lista de propriedades do meu obj, ele me exibe a lista de métodos que o List<> tem, por isso falei de fazer no HTML, nesse caso, o atributo name dos campos HTML do fomr de contato ficariam como para fazer o binding corretamente?

Comment: É só fazer um foreach na view.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.